# How to mute my app programmatically (disable sounds)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webkit, avfoundation

I'm creating an app-browser that hides advertising. Almost done. Sometimes there are autoplaying sounds in browser(probably powered with JavaScript)

Now I need to turn off all sounds in this app. I've tried two ways: through AVFoundation and through WebKit.

Please help me to get idea how I can do this. One more variants are were welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done through the `MediaPlayer` module:

```
(MPVolumeView().subviews.filter{ NSStringFromClass($0.classForCoder) == "MPVolumeSlider" }.first as? UISlider)?.setValue(0, animated: false)
```

Note the two values you can change:

```
value: how much volume you want (0 in this case)
animated: allowing you to animate the change visually
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I can't rate your answer because of my low reputation. This works for me. Also I would like to know - how can I mute my app avoiding turn off background music (from Audio player) Like this: music player is playing in background and this app is muted for at the same time.

Comment: @AndreySinyagin you can click the check mark to accept the answer. Regarding your other issue, I’m not sure if you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

```
//isMuted is a variable i use to check for the mute mode 
if isMuted == true {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.ambient, 
                mode: .default, options: .mixWithOthers)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        
    }
    else {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: .mixWithOthers)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5 / Xcode 11**

Step 1:

```
import MediaPlayer
```

Step 2:

```
let slider = MPVolumeView().subviews.first(where: { $0 is UISlider }) as? UISlider
```

Step 3:

```
slider?.setValue(0.0, animated: false)
```